# How can I backup and restore .zip file on iCloud Drive?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud

I want to store .zip files on iCloud. Anybody help me how to upload and restore? I have read the Apple guideline for iCloud backup and now I have created one folder with some files and two folders with multiple images and then generate zip file of that folder.

Comment: Please share your code so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First Save your File and Folder on Local Storage.
2. Then Create this File & Folder's Zip File.
3. And Last Upload Your zip file on iCloud.
4. For get this file doing reverse process.

```html
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self CreatFileAndFolder];

}
```

> Create Folder on local and save file in this folder that you want upload on iCloud Drive.

```html
-(void)CreatFileAndFolder{

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/meetInChat"];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];


    NSString *stringToWrite = @"1\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n41\n2\n3\n4";


    NSString *exportPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingString:@"/mytext.txt"];
    [stringToWrite writeToFile:exportPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

}
```

> Create Action that First Create Zip file your Folder and then Upload your Zip file on iCloud Drive.

```html
-(IBAction) iCloudSyncing:(id)sender
{
    [self zipFolder];

    //--------------------------Zip Folder Upload on iCloud-----------------------------//

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"meetInChat.zip"];
    NSLog(@"FilePath=>%@",zipFilePath);
    NSURL *u = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:zipFilePath];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u];

    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"meetInChat.zip"];
    Mydoc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    Mydoc.zipDataContent = data;

    [Mydoc saveToURL:[Mydoc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"PictureZip: Synced with icloud");

             [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]setData:data forKey:@"meetInChat"];
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"PictureZip: Syncing FAILED with icloud");

     }];
}
```

> Create Zip file from your folder

```html
-(BOOL)zipFolder
{

//--------------------------Create Zip Folder -----------------------------//
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isDir=NO;
    NSArray *subpaths = nil;
    NSString *exportPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/meetInChat"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:exportPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir){
        subpaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:exportPath];
    }

    NSString *meetInChatPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.zip",@"meetInChat"]];

    ZipArchive *archiver = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    [archiver CreateZipFile2:meetInChatPath];


    if (isDir) {
        for(NSString *path in subpaths){
            NSString *fullPath = [exportPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
            if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath isDirectory:&isDir] && !isDir){
                [archiver addFileToZip:fullPath newname:path];
            }
        }
    } else {
        [archiver addFileToZip:exportPath newname:@"meetInChat"];
    }

    BOOL successCompressing = [archiver CloseZipFile2];
    if(successCompressing)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

> Here Get ZipFile back From iCloud Drive then Doing reverse process Unzip your file and get data back.

```
- (IBAction)GetData:(id)sender {

    //--------------------------Get data back from iCloud -----------------------------//
    id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
    if (token == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"ICloud Is not LogIn");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ICloud Is LogIn");

        NSData *dataFile = [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore]dataForKey:@"meetInChat"];

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"meetInChat.zip"];
        NSString* fileAtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        [dataFile writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];

    }      
}
```

Comment: Nice saved my day, for others MyDocument is the subclass of UIDocument